# Can a plasmid cause cancer?

Tags: cancer, plasmids, human-genome, yeast, retrovirus

Can a plasmid cause cancer?
According to [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasmid), plasmids are normally present in bacteria

> They (plasmids) are normally present in bacteria , and sometimes in eukaryotic organisms such as yeast [(my translation)]

Let's say we inject yeast (by digestive tract) into a H. Sapiens (we will be focused in the yeast's plasmid only). Is it possible for plasmids to get into eukaryotic cells presents in the digestive tract?

Comment: *Is it possible for plasmids to get into eukaryotic cells presents in the digestive tract?* is a completely different question

Answer (score 1):

Canonically, bacterial plasmids will **not** replicate in eukaryotic systems, due to a lack of the necessary control (regulatory) elements which will lead to expression.

It is possible though to construct [shuttle vectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuttle_vector) that can propagate in prokaryotes and eukaryotic cells (e.g. yeast or mammalian cells like the immortal HeLa cervical cancer-derived cell line).

What you are specifically asking is *whether horizontal (lateral) gene transfer between prokaryotes and eukaryotes occurs, and whether it has an effect on the eukaryotic cell.* [This 2016 paper](http://mbio.asm.org/content/7/4/e00863-16.full) is an excellent and recent article discussing this question.

> Can a plasmid cause cancer?

It has never been demonstrated, to my knowledge.

> Is it possible for plasmids to get into eukaryotic cells presents in
>   the digestive tract?

Very few bacteria can penetrate a healthy intestinal lining. However, in many  disorders of the gastrointestinal system, such as in inflammatory bowel disorders, the intestinal lining is compromised, which certainly allows the passage of prokaryotes and/or DNA into human circulation. However, a functional transfer of plasmids from prokaryotes to eukaryotic cells is not demonstrated. Whether the hypothetical transfer would lead to carcinogenesis is also not demonstrated.

Comment: A wide variety of intestinal bacteria leave their compartment and cause disease at other sites. This happens all the time.  Often enough that there is at least one patient in your local hospital for exactly this reason right now :)

Comment: I want to understand what you mean, the comment is unclear in intent. Gut microbes cause disease all over the body, but can they cross a healthy intestinal lining and the gut-blood barrier? And can you give an example of a disease 'at other sites' caused specifically by gut microbe infiltration, so we are on the same page? Gastroenterology is a very rich field and it's not my strongest point and the specifics are, well, quite specific. Cheers!

Comment: The intent of the comment is to correct an error in your answer. Pathogenic enterobacteriaceae often penetrate the intestinal lining. This is a common cause of sepsis, endocarditis, meningitis, and a rare cause of pneumonia (pneumonia that cultures positive for enterobacteriaceae is more often due to aspiration). Certain types of gastroenteritis are caused by invasive infection as well. Your gut is a good barrier most of the time, but gut and mouth bugs often get through. Sometimes the result is transient bacteremia. Sometimes it is disease.

Comment: I stand by the statement that *very few bacteria* penetrate healthy intestinal lining. Perhaps I should have mentioned it is known that even in healthy individuals, there exist small amounts of viable bacteria in the urine and in healthy blood, even though, in medical circles, both are typically referred to as sterile environments. And, as you say, if any lining is compromised, bacteria and other microbes will certainly access circulation.

Comment: the statement you're standing by is unsourced and disagrees with my medical and infectious disease specialist training, my clinical experience, and basic textbooks on medical microbiology, internal medicine, and infectious disease.

Comment: Look, you wrote an otherwise good answer with an error in it. I'm trying to help you make it a better answer. :)

Comment: Clearly we are talking about different things. Help me understand: you're talking about special, medical cases in which bacteria pass from the lumen into the body. I don't doubt that. And I'm talking about the general case, where a healthy intestinal epithelium is, albeit a rich bacterial niche, an entry barrier for organisms even as small as bacteria. From Medical Microbiology, ch. 95: Microbiology of the Gastrointestinal Tract: *Once the mucosal barrier is breached*, bacteria penetrate through the intestinal wall into the *normally sterile* peritoneal cavity and its surrounding structures."

Comment: Happy to help :) You are correct. A healthy intestinal epithelium is an entry barrier for pathogens. The thing to remember, though, is that, while normal physiology (barrier holds) is normal, pathological processes are common. That barrier is violated in every living human. Sterile compartments are sterile, not just because of barriers, but because of active clearance mechanisms within the sterile compartment. Consider, for example, the neutropenic patient. One of the most common complications in these patients is gram negative bacteremia of enteric origin.

Comment: Bacteria get through. When they do, if we have enough WBCs, they clear them (among other mechanisms), which involves bacteria getting into eukaroytic cells. Your answer is good. Horizontal transfer of a plasmid from a prokaryote to a human would be an unexpected and exciting finding. The final point you try to make supporting that argument is just a little off because of a common misunderstanding (held by many very smart and accomplished people), which I expect you hold because you just haven't had the very specific education that would help you understand how often pathologic processes occur.

Comment: these are not special medical cases, they are common, everyday medical cases that have occurred in every living human :)

Comment: Very good! Upon review, my last sentence could be misinterpreted, or worse, could be misleading - I've adjusted it to clarify that it's not an *in principle* case but an *in practice* case of prokaryotes passing into human circulation. I hope it will be clear to anyone reading that prokaryotes are found in what is referred to as 'sterile' bodily fluids, and they become especially prominent and potentially problematic if barriers and/or clearance mechanisms are compromised. Glad we rounded it up and added a few supplementary points as an addendum for others to peruse. Cheers!

Comment: good edit. I'm still not going to upvote, though, because you still seem to misunderstand that this statement: `Very few bacteria can penetrate a healthy intestinal lining` is incorrect. A wide variety of bacteria can penetrate a healthy intestinal lining, and they do so in the absence of prior gastrointestinal disease. The blood compartment, for example, stays sterile because WBCs clear those bacteria. The physical barrier is only part of the mechanism. A sterile compartment stays sterile because of active clearance mechanisms.

Comment: Your rudimentary statements are correct. However, what you *now* (finally clearly) stated is absolutely far from being correct and has never been demonstrated. Provide sources if you make strong claims like `A wide variety of bacteria can penetrate a healthy intestinal lining, and they do so in the absence of prior gastrointestinal disease.` Some reasons below:

Comment: (i) only a very small fraction of total bacteria cross the lining even when the entire barrier is disrupted to an extreme extent. (ii) only a very small fraction of bacteria functionally equip hemolysins or other known toxins to lyse enterocytes or disrupt tight junctions, or affect their shape in order to penetrate the lining. (iii) even affected enterocytes purge their contents into the lumen (Chassaing et al. 2017) (iv) even inflamed gut linings, like in colitis, are permeable only to small molecules, and permit no access to bacteria.

Comment: (v) in the vast, vast majority of gastrointestinal issues (i.e. abnormal conditions) what is known and demonstrated to occur is the expulsion of water and other small molecules, activation of the nervous and endocrinological system but not the entry of bacteria. (vii) bacterial encroachment has not been observed nor documented in any person who is not disposed or immunocompromised. in fact, it is only observed in diseased people, and only in very limited parts of the digestive tract. **My two cents:** Very small fractions of very few types of bacteria rarely cross a normal gut lining.

Comment: I've been saying the same thing ever since my first comment. Many species of bacteria leave the GI compartment. I see this all the time in clinical practice. Certainly the dose is small, but it happens often. The gut is not a perfect barrier. Active clearance mechanisms are also needed in order to maintain sterile compartments. If you would like me to answer more thoroughly than I have in this long back and forth comment section, feel free to ask a question.

Comment: `I see this all the time in clinical practice` reveals bias, no? Unlike anecdotal medical practice, I'm sure you understand very well that biology, and also epidemiology, rely on experiment and statistics, and the *very central concept of random sampling*. This determines the healthy norm. By way of example: pulmonary embolisms are not the norm, they are extreme events, and no internist making the case that _they happen to everyone if they live long enough_ should convince us that thrombogenesis is a frequently-occurring, healthy, normal occurrence in lung vasculature. Let's agree to disagree.

Comment: I seem to be failing to communicate the issue here, because you keep misunderstanding. For your analogy, sepsis would be the pulmonary embolism, bacteria escaping from the GI compartment and being cleared by the immune system would be clot formation. Clot formation happens often. Bacteria are often stopped by the immune system rather than the epithelial barrier. We know a barrier is not sufficient to prevent enteric bacteria from disseminating to other sites. I'm well aware of the importance of appropriate statistical methods. I teach those methods to residents and other physicians.

Comment: Your statement was in the context of an argument about bacteria somehow not being near eukaryotic cells on a population level. The relevant frequencies here are not the average or most common state of the GI tract. This is a pathophysiology question. Does this happen with a frequency that could cause disease? That's the question.

Comment: I agree with your conclusion (I don't believe plasmid transfer between prokaryotes and humans occurs), but your barrier argument doesn't make sense in this context exactly because this is already a well established mechanism for pathogenesis in infectious disease. Here, the identification of enteric pathogens in many body compartments in clinical practice is exactly the kind of data that counters the argument "*bacteria can't do this because they don't cross the barrier*". You do not need to establish, e.g., the prevalence of positive blood cultures in a healthy population.

Comment: In addition to understanding the importance and role of random sampling, if you want to progress in your field and do good work, you need to understand which class of data allows you to draw which conclusions and what kind of evidence supports, suggests, or opposes what kind of hypothesis.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82083/discussion-between-de-novo-and-s-pr).